# Convert XML data to Pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I want to extract data from an XML and convert it to Pandas Data Frame

First off i tried importing with Element Tree xml and just print out some of the columns with this code, no luck

So for now i've managed to extract some of the data with this code

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None
def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("RTS_XTV100006361.xml")
    dfcols = ['start', 'stop', 'channel', 'type', 'title', 'category']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)
    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        start = node.attrib.get('start')
        stop = node.attrib.get('stop')
        channel = node.attrib.get('channel')
        type = node.attrib.get('type')
        title = node.find('title')
        category = node.find('category')
        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([start, stop, channel, type, getvalueofnode(category), getvalueofnode(title)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)
    print (df_xml)'
```

**But title  and category are still empty**

This is example of XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tv xmlns="http://www.xmltv.org/xmltv" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <programme ID="58135" start="20200528000000 +0200" stop="20200528013000 +0200" channel="XTV100006361" recordable="Y" npvrenable="Y" cpvrenable="N" type="program" deleted="false">
    <blackoutInfo>
      <isBlackout>1</isBlackout>
      <groupIDs>2</groupIDs>
      <streams>00000001</streams>
    </blackoutInfo>
    <title lang="sr"><![CDATA[Yoga retreat]]></title>
    <category lang="sr"><![CDATA[Entertainment]]></category>
    <icon src="default_playbill.png" ptype="3" />
    <episode-num system="xmltv_ns">0.0.0</episode-num>
  </programme>
  <programme ID="58136" start="20200528013000 +0200" stop="20200528030000 +0200" channel="XTV100006361" recordable="Y" npvrenable="Y" cpvrenable="N" type="program" deleted="false">
    <blackoutInfo>
      <isBlackout>1</isBlackout>
      <groupIDs>2</groupIDs>
      <streams>00000001</streams>
    </blackoutInfo>
    <title lang="sr"><![CDATA[Doctor Who]]></title>
    <category lang="sr"><![CDATA[Entertainment]]></category>
    <icon src="default_playbill.png" ptype="3" />
    <episode-num system="xmltv_ns">0.0.0</episode-num>
  </programme>
</tv>
```

desired output that i would like is that i get this columns:

> channel, start, stop, title, category

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 1):

The XML document uses a default namespace (`http://www.xmltv.org/xmltv`).

One way to do what you want is to use `findall()` and `find()` with a wildcard (`{*}`) for the namespace. This works with [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#xml).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

def getvalueofnode(node):
    return node.text if node is not None else None

def main():
    parsed_xml = et.parse("RTS_XTV100006361.xml")
    dfcols = ['start', 'stop', 'channel', 'type', 'title', 'category']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for programme in parsed_xml.findall("{*}programme"):
        start = programme.get('start')
        stop = programme.get('stop')
        channel = programme.get('channel')
        type = programme.get('type')

        title = programme.find('{*}title')
        category = programme.find('{*}category')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([start, stop, channel, type,
                       getvalueofnode(title), getvalueofnode(category)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    pd.options.display.width = 0
    print (df_xml)

main()
```

Result:

```
                  start                  stop       channel     type         title       category
0  20200528000000 +0200  20200528013000 +0200  XTV100006361  program  Yoga retreat  Entertainment
1  20200528013000 +0200  20200528030000 +0200  XTV100006361  program    Doctor Who  Entertainment
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped me organize my data

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @mzjn, there is a default namespace for the XML; you'll have to use it in your computation

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    root = ET.parse("RTS_XTV100006361.xml")
    #declare namespace
    ns = '{http://www.xmltv.org/xmltv}'
    
    #required keys
    keys = ['channel','start','stop','type']
    box = []
    for ent in root.findall(f".//{ns}programme"):
        d = {key:value for key,value in ent.attrib.items() if key in keys}
        #attach title and category to dictionary
        d.update({"title" : ent.find(f".//{ns}title").text,
                  "category" : ent.find(f".//{ns}category").text
                 })
        box.append(d)
        
    return pd.DataFrame(box)

main()

           start                  stop               channel         type   title            category
0   20200528000000 +0200    20200528013000 +0200    XTV100006361    program Yoga retreat    Entertainment
1   20200528013000 +0200    20200528030000 +0200    XTV100006361    program Doctor Who      Entertainment
```